# Constructing an algebraically closed extension-field of an already algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Given an arbitrary **algebraically closed** field F, can we always construct a 'superfield' K such that F<K and K is also algebraically closed? If so, how?

I'm curious whether you can always extend an already closed field to get a 'bigger' field that contains it (as a distinct subset).

An example of two fields with this property would be the algebraic numbers and the complex numbers. Both are algebraically closed, and yet the complex numbers extend the algebraic numbers.

Comment: Yes. First extend your field $\mathbb F$ with one additional element (say, $x$) - which basically makes up the field of *rational functions* $\mathbb F(x)$ over $\mathbb F$. Then, make up the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F(x)$.

Comment: So obvious, thanks a lot!

Comment: You can add as many additional transcendental elements as you want. All you have to do is to add the element and its inverse: $\mathbb{F}\subsetneq \mathbb{F}(\alpha ,1/\alpha )$. Since $\alpha \cdot (1/\alpha )=1$ you have an algebraic element in the extension field.

Comment: Note that any such extension can't be algebraic and hence the natural recourse is to adjoin some transcendental elements and then find another algebraic closure.